# JFrame - accessing my window from keylistener class

Tags: java, jframe

I am creating JFrame window In one class called Core and then in Main creating the window like this:

```
Core window = new Core("GAME1", 0, 0, true, true);
```

But then I decided to use keylistener and I created another class called Core_ControlsL:
My problem is that in here:

```
 else if(keyCode == 113)
      {
         GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(this.window);
      }
```

I cannot figure out how to access window so that when I press F2 it goes into full screen again.

```
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
```

This is my main.java:

```
public class Main
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException
   {
         Core window = new Core("GAME1", 0, 0, true, true);
   }
}
```

This is the Core.java:

```
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Core extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
   private final String Game_Title;
   private int Window_Width;
   private int Window_Height;
   private boolean isVisible;
   private boolean isResizeable;

   public Core(String Game_Title, int Window_Width, int Window_Height, boolean isVisible, boolean isResizeable) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException
   {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

      this.Game_Title = Game_Title;
      this.Window_Width = Window_Height;
      this.Window_Height = Window_Height;
      this.isResizeable = isResizeable;
      this.isVisible = isVisible;

      //Create JFrame
      JFrame window = new JFrame(Game_Title);
      window.setSize(Window_Width, Window_Height);
      window.setResizable(isResizeable);
      window.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
      window.setVisible(isVisible);
      window.addKeyListener(new Core_Controls());
      window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(window); // make window full screen

   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {

   }
}
```

And the     Core_Controls.java:

```
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Core_Controls implements KeyListener
{
   @Override
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
   {
   }

   @Override
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
   {
      int keyCode;
      keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
      System.out.println(keyCode); // LLLLLL
      if(keyCode == 112)
      {
         GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(null);
      }
      else if(keyCode == 113)
      {
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(null);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Still trying to figure this one out....

Answer (score 1):

Pass the window to the listener:

```
Core window = new Core("GAME1", 0, 0, true, true);
Core_ControlsL listener = new Core_ControlsL(window);
```

While you're at it, rename your class so that it reaspects the standard Java naming conventions. And use complete words instead of unreadable abbreviations. You'll thank yourself in 2 weeks when you'll re-read your own code.

Comment: I edit my code so you can see exactly what's going on I started learning Java this year in uni and I'm still new with it, any code optimizations are quite welcome.
It's not like I'm trying to build entire game, rather just practice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use "magic numbers". "112" and "113" don't mean anything to anybody else reading the code.
2. Better yet, don't use a KeyListener.

Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`. Check out Key Bindings for some basic information as well as a link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Key Bindings` and links to working examples with key bindings.